# MySQL connection doesn't work in Android without specific error

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have this problem when I try to connect to my MySQL database. It gives me out that it's wrong and I don't know why because it doesn't give me a **specific error**.

It just gives me out what I wrote in the catch. 
BTW I'm using MySQL Connector/J Version 5.1.47.

This is the connection Code:

```
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String msg = "";
    //JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_URL + "/" +
            DbStrings.DATABASE_NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ProgressTextView.setText("Connecting to Database...");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DbStrings.USERNAME, DbStrings.PASSWORD);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM zimmerstamm";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String Bemerkung = rs.getString("Bemerkung");
                Double Zimmer = rs.getDouble("Zimmer");

                fruitsMap.put(Bemerkung, Zimmer);
            }
            msg = "Process complete";

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException connError) {
            msg = "An exception was thrwon for JDBC.";
            connError.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            msg = "And exception was No class found.";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: "It just gives me out what i wrote in the catch" and the stack is not printed ? First problem then, rebuild your project. For the solution, are you sure your server is accessible, are you on a local or mobile network ?

Comment: The only thing that comes out red is this **E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da** but as far a I know this error has nothing to do with it. I already Rebuild it. Im working on a localhost.

Comment: You shouldn't use JDBC connections from Android applications. Use a REST service that mediates between your application and the database.

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for the output in the wrong place.  Is standard output being redirected?  Within the application itself?  In a wrapper script that launches the app?  On the command line?